# Count the Number of Records after Replacing Duplicate Values

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-arguments

One job runs on the server and it creates a file like below:

```
1000727888004
522101 John Smith
522101 John Smith
522188 Shelly King
522188 Shelly King
1000727888002
522990 John Doe
522990 John Doe
9000006000000
```

Currently, we are in the process to fix the code but that will take a month. In the mean time, I am using a command to remove the duplicate records like below.

```
perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;' old_file.txt > new_file.txt
```

After I run the above command, it removes the duplicate entries but counts remain same as below:

```
1000727888004
522101 John Smith
522188 Shelly King
1000727888002
522990 John Doe
9000006000000
```

last number for row starting with 1 is the total count (so 4 should have been 2 in the first line and 2 should have been 1 in the fourth line and 6 should have been 3 in the last line starting with 9). It should look like below:

```
1000727888002
522101 John Smith
522188 Shelly King
1000727888001
522990 John Doe
9000003000000
```

I could not come up with any logic that would fix it. I need help here. Can I run another command or add something in my perl command to correct the count as well. Yes, I can open the file in Notepad++ and fix the numbers manually but I am trying to get it automated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is that last record, starting with 9?

Comment: that is the trailer of the file with total count. First 9 is always present and then the next 6 numbers are the count..if it is in one digit then 5 zeros are padded on left. and last 6 numbers are always 0

Answer (score 0):

In awk. It processes the dupes within the "blocks" between count records, ie. it does not consider duplicates within the whole file. If this is incorrect assumption let me know.

```
$ awk '
NF==1 {          # for the cout record 
    if(c!="")    # this fixes leading empty row
        print c  # print count
    for(i in a)  # all deduped data records
        print i  # print them
    delete a     # empty hash
    c=$0         # store count (well, you could use just the first count record)
    next         # for this record don't process further
}
{
    if($0 in a)  # if current record is already in a
        c--      # decrease count
    else a[$0]   # else hash it
}
END {            # last record handling
    print c      # print the last record
    for(i in a)  # just in case last record would be missing
        print i  # this and above could be removes
}' file
```

Output:

```
1000727888002
522101 John Smith
522188 Shelly King
1000727888001
522990 John Doe
9000006000000
```

If the dupes are removed in the whole file and the last record was the count also:

```
awk '
NF==1 {
    if(NR==1)
        c=$0
    print c
} 
NF>1 {
    if($0 in a)
        c--
    else {
        a[$0]
        print
    }
}' file
1000727888004
522101 John Smith
522188 Shelly King
1000727888002
522990 John Doe
1000727888001
```